# Javascript Higher Order Functions and DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, higher-order-functions

I am working on a project that takes text that a user inputs in a text box and returns the most common word.

Javascript:

```
var bestMode = 1;
var currentMode = 0;
var character;

function Find_Word(){
  var words = document.getElementById('words').innerText;
  var punctuationless = words.replace(/['!"#$%&\\'()\*+,\-\.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^_`{|}~']/g,"");
  var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
  var WordList = finalString.split(" ");
  return FindMode(WordList);
}

function FindMode(WordList){
  for(var i=0; i<WordList.length; i++){
    for(var m=i; m<WordList.length; m++){
      if(WordList[i] == WordList[m]){
        currentMode += 1;
      }
      if(bestMode<currentMode){
        bestMode = currentMode;
        character = WordList[i];
      }
    }
    currentMode = 0;
  }
}
console.log(bestMode);
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Most common word used</h1>
  <input type="text" id="words" rows="10" columns="30"></input>
  <button type="button" id="FindWord" onclick="Find_Word()">Find Word</button>
<script src="CommonWord.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I can't figure out is the correct way to pull text from the text box into a variable as one string. My function Find_Word takes the received string when the button is pressed and strips away punctuation and leaves an array WordList with with each individual word in the string.

After that, I also can't understand how to pass that array into my second function findMode where I iterate through each value of the array to find the most common word. That is saved in the variable bestMode.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are both getting the current text and passing the array correctly (although perhaps you should get the textbox value using the .value property).  What problem are you having exactly?  I am not sure what FindMode is supposed to do either.

Here is some script that is based on what you posted that sorts "words" according to how often they appear :

```
(function(w) {
    w.Sort_Words = function(words) {
        var o = {}, l = [];
        for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
            if (typeof o[words[i]] === 'undefined') {
                o[words[i]] = 0;
                l.push(words[i]);
            }
            o[words[i]] ++;
        }
        l.sort(function(a, b) { return o[b] - o[a]; });
        return l;
    };

    w.Find_Word = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById('words').value;
        var words = text.replace(/['!"#$%&\\'()\*+,\-\.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]\^_`{|}~']/g,"").replace(/\s{2,}/g," ").split(' ');
        var sorted = w.Sort_Words(words);
        document.getElementById('results').innerText = sorted.length === 0 ?
            'You must type at least one word' : 
            'The most commonly used word was: ' + sorted[0];
    };
})(window);
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/4u1mv20h/4/